Balanced vs. unbalanced panel
I am conducting a fixed effects model analysis using unbalanced panel data. Should I balance the data first, or is it better to proceed with the unbalanced data? What are the trade-offs or implications of each approach?
I tried to run them both and they lead to similar estimates, but I was wondering if there is a best-practice on how to decide which approach is the "more correct" one?
